# How to add loader to firebase requests?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using [rnfirebase](https://rnfirebase.io/).

I'm looking for a way to place an interceptor in the firestore's requests.

Because? I would like to add a global loader to display a spinner every time I make a call to the FIREBASE API.

**Makes sense?**

package.json

```
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore APIs don't offer any sort of global listener that responds to any and all queries that might be happening.  That's sounds like something you'll need to implement on your own by wrapping the provided APIs.